# Run javascript after third party script runs

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an issue with a third party script running asynchronously. This third party script loads a form to a page.  I have code such as:

```
$(document).ready( function() {

  // functions and stuff that alter form fields
  // such as passing a parameter to a hidden field

});
```

My issue is that all of my code runs before the form loads. How do I allow the third party to run then execute my code once the form is loaded? I've read so many guides on similar questions that I've gone down a rabbit hole and think I'm missing something obvious.

**Edit:** A comment made me realize I should probably have included that I'm using a cms that builds a "shortcode" which adds the form and scripts to the page.

Comment: Does the third party script have any mechanism to let you know it has finished loading?  Google Maps has you supply a `callback` parameter in the URL you use to load the library.  See [Google Maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial).  If you library does not have a similar mechanism, you will have difficulty differentiating between the script being loaded and actually being initialized.

Comment: I'm working with the provider in hopes they can help me identify if it does. It doesn't appear so.

Comment: The gross way to do it if there is no callback is to use a `setInterval` to poll for whatever exposed piece of the API you need to wait for checking to see if it still `undefined`.  However, that can still lead to timing issues if the API exposes the variable too soon.  I'll write an example as an answer.

Comment: How is this script loaded?  Do you have a `<script src="">` tag to it somewhere in your markup?

Comment: I don't get to see the script tag unfortunately (at least not until the page is constructed).  The cms gives a shortcode for the form which the inputs, scripts, etc. build from.  The setInterval method was something I was attempting before but had little luck.

Answer (score 0):

You could load the third party script using $.getScript, then have your code executed as a callback

```
    $(function() {
        $.getScript(url, function(){
           //Your code

          }); 
    });
```

https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/

Comment: This would be perfect if I could identify just the script. Compounding the issue is the fact that the cms creates a "form" shortcode and builds it to the page. This prevents me from doing something like this.